# Using Dashcode's List Controller without their DataSource option

Tags: javascript, json, dashcode

I'm working on my own custom google calendar, so far i'm able to get everything to work, i've loaded all the data and everything works great, each event shows up on a select box.

What i want to do now is to load each event name on the LIST part. How exactly can i do that? i'm very lost with it.

I looked at the sample code that dashcode has for the list part but i really am lost with populating the list in real time, can somebody help me? i can provide more info as needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In dashcode under library/code there is an example titled 'List Data Source'. You will also need to alter the list object datatype to dynamic and then select your datasource from the dropdown list.